# Ant flaka: modify each elements of a list

Tags: ant, flaka

I have this list:

```
<c:let>
    a = list('a','b','c')
</c:let>
```

How can i modify each elements for that list?

I need something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] += 'd';
}
```

I looked in the tutorial, but the examples show only how to retrieve a list element, not how to modify it.

So, **how can i modify list elements, iterating on it?**

*Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (currently) no function which lets you manipulate lists. All you could do is

```
<let>
  a = list('a', 'b', .. )    ; your list
  b = list()                 ; empty list 
</let>
<for var=" item " in=" a ">
 <let>
   x = some-el-expression( item ) ;     
   b = append(b, x)
 </let>
</for>
<let>
 a = b
</let>
```

Work has started which allows one to use functions with arguments - besides the convenience functions (append() and other functions listed in section 3.6 of the [manual](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/downloads/detail?name=flaka.pdf)). Other work has also been started to allow you to plugin your own functions (would require Java programming - providing functions via Groovy or (J)Ruby needs some research).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any tutorial on how to plugin my own functions?

Comment: Sorry, plugin support is not yet working, not even as kind of beta.